# Working with basic Node OAuth redirect following

Tags: node.js, oauth

Still confused about one point with node.

I’ve got a server running at http://localhost:3030 to listen for the hit from the redirect, but the redirect never comes.

How, in Node, do you have the request *actually* follow the redirects. And end up at
http://localhost:3030/?code=ccf3d214669645f594b59be14032e20d

Here is the link; In the browser it does end up in the right place
https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=8901edf0746b460489427434ba5d321e&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3030&response_type=code

Comment: Please add relevant code it's impossible to answer without looking at it. What's the "master/root" route?

Comment: @Michelem the routes aren’t important, I can make those whatever they need to be

Answer (score 2):

The `authorization_code` flow requires a browser, because the user have to be redirected to the third party web site to log in and authenticate your app, in this case that's the Instagram website. So you do need a browser to redirect you back to your `redirect_url` with the `code` parameter.

For that type of OAuth flow you can use [Grant](https://github.com/simov/grant). You don't have to implement the OAuth flow by yourself. Just follow the [basic example](https://github.com/simov/grant/tree/master/example/basic) and replace `facebook` with `instagram`. As you can see you have a basic web server there and you have to navigate to the `/connect/instagram` route in your web browser. The only difference is that Grant will handle the heavy lifting for you, so you'll receive just the `access_token` at the end.

You can test the Instagram flow [here](https://grant-oauth.herokuapp.com/#/instagram).

Comment: So there’s no way to connect to the instagram API without a browser? That doesn’t sound right.

Comment: There are a two other less secure OAuth flows such as [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2#grant-type-resource-owner-password-credentials) and [Client Credentials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2#grant-type-client-credentials) that doesn't require a browser, but Instagram doesn't seem to [support them](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

Comment: Okay, so what about using a browser driver like Protractor to actually visit it for you, etc. That would be 100% server side. It just seems ridiculous to necessitate the frontend in a full backend auth process where there is no third-party "user" involved. Does the frontend need to be logged in?

Comment: I understand, the *Client Credentials* flow is designed exactly for granting access to the application itself. Automating the browser process might be possible with [node-webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) - you'll have to fill in the user's name and password and then grant access to your app.

Comment: That’s my point, there is no "user", because it isn’t providing a service to others, it is simply the account the developer account and the service.

Answer (score 2):

My first answer and comments are still valid, but I'm going to show you how you can automate the authorization process with [nwjs](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js).

First you need to enable the Implicit flow for your OAuth app - under the Security tab.

For the purpose of this demo I'm using `http://localhost:3000/callback` as redirect URI for my OAuth app. So you need to add it as additional redirect URL of your OAuth app. Also fill in all of the required credentials in `authorization.html`.

#### server.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')
var http = require('http')
var url = require('url')
var qs = require('querystring')
var child = require('child_process')

var nw = null
var server = http.createServer()

server.on('request', function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/connect') {
    var dpath = path.resolve(__dirname)
    nw = child.spawn('nw', [dpath])
    res.end()
  }
  else if (req.url == '/callback') {
    var fpath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'token.html')
    var body = fs.readFileSync(fpath, 'utf8')
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'})
    res.end(body)
  }
  else if (/^\/token/.test(req.url)) {
    var uri = url.parse(req.url)
    var query = qs.parse(uri.query)
    console.log(query)
    nw.on('close', function (code, signal) {
      console.log('NW closed')
    })
    nw.kill('SIGHUP')
    res.end()
  }
})

server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('HTTP server listening on port ' + 3000)
})
```

Start it with:

```
node server.js
```

Then navigate to `http://localhost:3000/connect`, you can use your browser for now.

#### authorize.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Client Side Implicit OAuth Flow</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var config = {
      client_id: '[CLIENT_ID]',
      redirect_uri: '[REDIRECT_URL]',
      username: '[USERNAME]',
      password: '[PASSWORD]'
    }

    var authorize_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?' +
      'client_id=' + config.client_id + '&' +
      'redirect_uri=' + config.redirect_uri + '&' +
      'response_type=token'

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
      var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe')
      iframe.setAttribute('src', authorize_url)
      iframe.onload = function (e) {
        var doc = this.contentWindow.document
        // login
        if (doc.querySelector('[name=username]')) {
          doc.querySelector('[name=username]').value = config.username
          doc.querySelector('[name=password]').value = config.password
          doc.querySelector('[type=submit]').click()
        }
        // authorize
        else if (doc.querySelector('[value=Authorize]')) {
          doc.querySelector('[value=Authorize]').click()
        }
      }
    }, false)
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src=""></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Once you hit that route a new process is spawned and the `authorize.html` is executed. Just keep in mind that NWjs requires some graphical libraries to be installed on your server, so it's not exactly a headless browser.

There the browser navigates to the authorization URL inside an iframe. Depending on whether you are logged in or already authorized the app different pages are loaded. This code just fills in your user name and password and clicks on a few links.

Once the OAuth flow is complete you get the `access_token` as hash in the URL. As you may know the browser doesn't send that part of the URL to the server, so in the `/callback` route the server returns another page called `token.html` which sole purpose is to extract the access token from the URL hash and return it as a querystring in the `/token` route.

#### token.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Client Side Implicit OAuth Flow</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var config = {
      callback_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/token'
    }

    var access_token = window.location.hash.replace('#access_token=', '')
    var url = config.callback_uri + '?access_token=' + access_token

    window.location.href = url
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

After you run this example you'll see your access token in the command line:

```
$ node server.js 
HTTP server listening on port 3000
{ access_token: '1404767371.e5610d0.3381e9a2fd7340d8b90b729f407949d2' }
NW closed
```

You can download all files from [here](https://gist.github.com/simov/015ae9f059e9b95cd85b).

Comment: @kirk-strobeck I though it would be interesting to implement the Explicit Server Side OAuth flow as well, using the same tools as the above ones. You can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/simov/d91a0c92dffe4a704fe7). 

I'm using [Grant](https://github.com/simov/grant) there just to help me with the OAuth flow but that's completely optional. As you can see the only difference with this flow is that the OAuth app credentials are stored on the server, and the `access_token` is returned in the querystring by default. Also there is one more step in the flow but that's hidden when using Grant.

Comment: Haven’t had a moment to try it yet, but excited to integrate this into a static server-side build. THX!