# How do I follow an oath 1.0 redirect with Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, single-sign-on

I'm using this API: https://github.com/JohnDeere/MyJohnDeereAPI-OAuth-NodeJS-Client and I can't follow the redirect on the back-end.

When I visit `localhost:3000/oauth` from the browser, the /callback endpoint gets called but I fetch it from the back end - the /callback end point doesn't get called.

This is the line that starts the redirect:

```
res.redirect(config.oauthAuthorizeRequestTokenUri.replace('{token}', token));
```

How do I follow redirects from the back-end?

This doesn't work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow-redirects

Is this the problem?

> The authorization_code flow requires a browser, because the user have
>   to be redirected to the third party web site to log in and
>   authenticate your app

[Working with basic Node OAuth redirect following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993650/working-with-basic-node-oauth-redirect-following)